# Peculiar use of the term "rationalization"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

> But whatever you call it, [Fordism] has been a system based 
>   on large-scale standardization and vertical organizations that require a strict division 
>   of labor and an extreme ***rationalization*** of each process. [emphasis mine]

I'm looking for perspectives on what the term "rationalization" might mean in this context - it seems to be a rather unique use of the term, and I'm curious about why it might have been chosen. Let me know if a longer excerpt is needed for more context - I'm curious about what can be deduced from this alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly OED meaning 1 (c), (of *rationalize*) is the meaning that Americans most frequently assume. But it only appears to date from 1922.

*c. Psychol. To explain or justify (one's behaviour or attitude) to oneself or others with plausible but specious reasons, usually unwittingly.*

Not surprisingly, the original meaning is *to make rational*, i.e. meaning 1 (a) of the OED..

*a. To explain on a rational basis, make conformable to reason; to make rational, consistent, or intelligible.*

It is very seldom that I have heard British people use meaning 1 (c), though it is clearly considered the principal meaning across the Atlantic.

Comment: I suspected the Atlantic was at play here... thanks!

Comment: @drewmore I know that in America it can be tantamount to accusing someone of infidelity, to accuse them of 'rationalizing'. It is a use which is largely foreign to most people in Britain.

Answer (score 1):

[Rationalization:](https://www.google.com/search?q=rationalization%20meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)

Rationalization means **organizing something into a logically coherent system.** Factory organization is often rationalized to make it as efficient as possible. Sometimes rationalization means a way someone justifies their action. I found this and I think the bolded language sounds like your case. I've usually thought of the second, "justification" meaning when thinking of the word.

Answer (score 1):

**Economic rationalization** concerns the efficient organization of processes, people, and machines. It is often used in the realm of production / manufacturing. Rationalizing a process or system is intended to increase productivity.

For an overview of economic rationalization, you can check out the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_%28economics%29

**Rationalization** sometimes refers more specifically to laying workers off in a drive for greater efficiency. We sometimes see *workforce rationalization* and *labor rationalization*. For a good example of "rationalization" being used as an alternative to "layoffs," see this page: http://www.ppiaf.org/sites/ppiaf.org/files/documents/toolkits/Portoolkit/Toolkit/module7/developing.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case, rationalization means "concentrated rational thought on or about."  It's what the word originally meant.

Comment: I suppose we can't avoid *thought* being relevant here, but I think in OP's context it's not so much a matter of *thinking* rationally about each process. More a matter of each process being implemented in a totally rational way (including nothing unnecessary, for historical or sentimental reasons, etc.).

Comment: That's just an extension of the result thinking process into a physical arrangement and the thought-out process to implement the desire.

Comment: I know, but if someone said *"We must rationalize this process"*, they're probably thinking more about ***making changes** so the process is more rational, focused, efficient*, rather than about having rational thoughts/discussion on how to do this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But all this is totally different to the meaning that the word has acquired in America (see my answer). A lot of Americans (I'm sure the OP is no exception) see it as the principal meaning of the word.